# I cannot access the value property from the material Ui Date-Picker

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-design, setstate

This is the DatePicker component that I created and I need to get the value after I have changed the date.

```
<DatePicker 
   onChange={(value) => this.dateChange(value)}
   hintText="Start Date" 
   mode="landscape" 
/>
```

This is the function to set date to the date that I clicked

```
dateChange = (value: any) => {
    this.setState({startDate: value})
}
```

When I console log either the value or this.state.startDate, I get the value null, but in every other example I've looked at, it looks like you can easily access the value by the value property.

Comment: which datepicker component exactly?

Comment: did you bind `dataChange` to the component? for instance something like `this.dataChange = this.dataChange.bind(this);` in your component constructor

Comment: This is the Material-UI sorry for not clarifying. Yes, I have it bound

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not super clear on what UI library you're using, but it looks like this one:

https://www.material-ui.com/#/components/date-picker

If that's the case, the value from the date picker is actually going to be the second parameter (as it is in all the controls from this library)

```
<DatePicker 
   onChange={this.dateChange}
   hintText="Start Date" 
   mode="landscape" 
/> 

dateChange = (e, value: any) => {
    this.setState({startDate: value})
}
```

It's slightly confusing - because the date picker component doesn't pass you the event that would normally be in the first parameter in other controls. `e` will be null, and `value` will be the date selected.

From the docs:

```
function(null: undefined, date: object) => void
```

Since there is no particular event associated with the change, the first argument will always be null.

Comment: Now I have an object that can't be rendered. And when I console log the object it just says Thu Apr 12 2018 00:00:00 GMT-0600 (MDT). How do I transform the object so I can put it in a p tag?

Comment: The value returned is a javascript `Date` object, if you don't know how to render a `Date` do a google search or open a new question. (hint, you need to convert it to a string)